# Fetch data from Firebase DB and display inside Widgets

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have recently started with Flutter and Firebase. Till now I have created a Form page to read the user inputs and upload it to the Firebase Realtime DB.
However, I do not know the best way to fetch the data from the DB and display inside the Widgets.

Till now I am able to do some workaround like below:

[image]

To achieve this I have used the below function to fetch the data into a list and then print the list.

```
  void readData() {
    ref.child("").onValue.listen((event) {
    DataSnapshot snapshot = event.snapshot;
  
    if (snapshot.value != null) {
      dataList.clear();
      if (snapshot.value is Map) {
      
        (snapshot.value as Map).forEach((key, value) {
          dataList.add("$key: $value");
      });
      setState(() {
      });
    }
  } else {
    print("No data available.");
  }
});
```

This gives me correct data but it is not at all organized and in a proper Widget. What I wanted to do is create a **separate widget** for each entry from the DB and **without** the IDs - "Nmc6zn*******".

Also, I am using ListView Builder for the above feature.

```
 child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dataList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  dataList[index],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                thickness: 1.0,
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering your question in 3 steps:

**1:**

> .. However, I do not know the best way to fetch the data from the DB and display inside the Widgets.

One way to achieve this would be to create a custom model representation of your data as it appears in Firestore. For example:

```dart
class MyModel {
  final String owner;
  final String email;

  MyModel({required this.owner, required this.email});

  factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return MyModel(
      owner: json['owner'] as String,
      email: json['email'] as String,
      // --> add other fields here
    );
  }
}
```

**2:**

> ... What I wanted to do is create a separate widget for each entry from the DB and without the IDs - "Nmc6zn*******".

Just create a sperate widget, and pass in your above-created model:

```dart
class CustomTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyModel model;
  const CustomTextWidget(this.model, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      model.owner, // <-- use the model here
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**3:**

Example usage:

```dart
 ListView.builder(
              itemCount: documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var data = documents[index].data() as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
                var model = MyModel.fromJson(data);
                return CustomTextWidget(model); // --->  Using the widget here
              },
            )
```

---

Here's a complete runnable example, (I'm using [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) instead of your `readData` method) view it in your IDE to get a better understanding:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // YOUR FIREBASE INITIALIZATION CODE HERE
  // for example:

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .snapshots(), // <-- Replace with your stream
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            var documents = snapshot.data?.docs ?? [];

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var data = documents[index].data() as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
                var model = MyModel.fromJson(data);
                return CustomTextWidget(model); // Use your custom widget here
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyModel {
  final String owner;
  final String email;

  MyModel({required this.owner, required this.email});

  factory MyModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return MyModel(
      owner: json['owner'] as String,
      email: json['email'] as String,
      // --> add other fields here
    );
  }
}

class CustomTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyModel model;
  const CustomTextWidget(this.model, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      model.owner, // <-- use the model here
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't work with Firebase Realtime DBs. I tried your way but the line - `var documents = snapshot.data?.docs ?? [];` is for Firestore DBs.